# Getting data from a container view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In my `UIViewController A` i have some container view, that loads some other `UIViewController B`.
I want that `UIViewController A` will be able to know what happens in its own container.

Problem is, that I can't get access from the container, to the view that is in it.
For example the container has a view controller with a `textfield` and i want to let viewA to know when someone started typing.

I must use `delegates`, or there is a way to get data from the container view ?

Comment: What is 'the container' that you call?  self.view behind UIViewController?  What's obvious is not necessarily obvious to others, at least not to idiots like me.

Comment: MVC.  Changes to the text field should be stored in some model class somewhere (possibly globally defined).  The view controller manages this input and once it's in the model you can see it everywhere.

Comment: @trojanfoe this is not the answer. i know how to share data. i need some kind of delegate, i want to inform a parent view on something that just happened. l Tomato ,you are not an idiot.. yes what you said is true, its a container view that i go to with self.view .

Answer (score 1):

A child `UIViewController can access it's parent with`parentViewController` and use it to send messages to the parent. You can do this directly, but...

Depending on the level of interaction it might be best to create an interface which the parent `UIViewController` implements. When the child `UIViewController` gets added to the parent, it gets a reference to a object implementing the interface. It provides a strong interaction between the objects, but also maintains proper encapsulation, and it is the delegate pattern.

So my answer is, you don't have to use the delegate pattern, but it seems like an appropriate solution. If you don't use the delegate pattern you might find yourself with a pair of objects so heavily coupled you might as well have just made it one object.

```
// Somewhere in your view controller A you want to add B as a child
B *b = [[B alloc] init]; // create view controller B
b.delegate = self;       // set up A as the delegate to B

// Add B as child
[self addChildViewController:b];
[self.containerView addSubview:b.view];
```

When `B` gets added as a child to `A` the delegate gets set. Assuming `A` implements an interface, `B` will have a property like `@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MySomethingDelegate> delegate;` `B` should be able to call any delegate method at any point.

Comment: Thanks. first of all i can't add a delegate listener to a view controller instance , because UIViewcontroller *sv , than would not allow to do [sv setDelegate:self] . SECOND , regarding your last option, can you show me some direction ? i could not understand what you means..

Comment: you can't do that. if i do B *b instead of UIViewcontroller *b , it wouldn't let me to add it as a child ...

Comment: `B` has to be a subclass of a `UIViewController`.